# Free module such that $R=R\oplus R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I was wondering if the following is correct:

Let $V=\bigoplus_{i\in\mathbb N}\mathbb Z$ and $R=\text{Hom}_{\ \mathbb Z}(V,V)$. Regard $R$ as an $R$-module. Then $R$ is free of rank $1$ with basis $\{\text{id}_{V}\}$. Now define a map $\phi$ as follows:

[image: Map \phi]
where $f_i: V \to \mathbb Z$ for each $f\in R$ are linear maps. Then $\phi$ is an isomorphism of $R$-modules.

Can I conclude as follows?

(1) Since $\phi$ is an isomorphism of $R$-modules we have $R\cong R^2$.

(2) Due to (1) we have $R^n\cong R^m$ for any $n,m\in\mathbb N$.

(3) Due to (2) we have that $R$ as an $R$-module is free of rank $k$ for any $k\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: Without sitting down to work out the details, my guess is that $\phi$ is a $\mathbb Z$-linear map but not an $R$-linear map.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, as Greg Martin guessed, that your $\phi$ is *not $R$-linear*. Let $1$ denote $\mathrm{id}_V\in  R$, and $f\in R$ arbitrary, then
$$\phi(f\cdot 1) \ne f\cdot \phi(1)\ .$$

Comment: Mhm, basically I was trying to find an explicit isomorphism for the following example:
http://img42.imageshack.us/img42/9227/modulesi.jpg

from https://www.math.lsu.edu/~adkins/m7211/AWchap3.pdf, see Remark 6.19 (2).

Comment: Ok. I'm not that sure any more.. Have you verified my inequality statement? I might also have overlooked something..

Comment: It seems that [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/72747/121097) shows that $\phi$ is indeed an isomorphism of $R$-modules.

Comment: Moreover, I've checked your claim $\phi(f\cdot 1)\ne f\cdot\phi(f)$ and it seems to be wrong.