# Can $R \times R$ be isomorphic to $R$ as rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I know from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72723/isomorphism-of-an-endomorphism-ring-how-can-r-cong-r2) that $R \times R$ can be isomorphic to $R$, as $R$-modules.

> But can they ever be isomorphic as rings?

Comment: Sure, make $R$ a direct sum of infinitely many copies of any ring.

Comment: @blue: a direct sum of unital rings need not be unital, though.

Comment: For preventing any confusion let me mention the following: for a *commutative* unitary ring $R$ it's not possible to have $R\times R\simeq R$ as $R$-modules.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sure, if $R=\prod_{i\in\mathbb N} \mathbb Z$ then $R\times R\cong R$.

Comment: The bijection from $R\times R\to R$ would be something like $(x_1,x_2,\ldots;y_1,y_2,\ldots)\mapsto(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2,\ldots)$.

Answer (score 4):

Sure. Take $R = \Pi_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb{Z}$ with the product ring structure. Then clearly
$R \times R$ is isomorphic to $R$. To find an isomorphism, just use some bijection $\mathbb{N} \amalg \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: This was already the answer of Thomas.

Comment: Oh right, thanks! @DietrichBurde I wrote the answer at the same time as him and then saw his answer. I decided to post it anyways, but I can of course delete it. I thought I would add a bit of more detail.