# Is it true that $R^n\simeq R^m$ as rings implies $m=n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. We know that if $R^n\simeq R^m$ as $R$-modules for some positive integers $n,m$ then $n=m$. But is it still true when they are isomorphic as rings? Thanks!

Comment: No, it's not! For a counterexample see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895428/can-r-times-r-be-isomorphic-to-r-as-rings).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Just take a ring $A$ and $R=\prod_{i\in I}A$, where $I$ is a countable set of index.

Comment: Do you want me to show that $R^n\simeq R^m$? There is nothing to prove... in this case $R^n$ is exactly **equal** to $R^m$.

Comment: Suppose $I=\Bbb N$, then $R^2=\prod_{i\in\Bbb N}A\times\prod_{i\in\Bbb N}A=\prod_{i\in\Bbb N}A=R$
because of some basic fact of how the cardinality of countable works

Comment: Two countable sets are in bijection, but not necessarily equal.

Comment: @user26857: They are not equal but the sets are used as indexing sets. So it seems to me that the products of A indexed by these two sets will be equal.

Comment: Given an element in $\prod_{i\in\Bbb N}A\times\prod_{i\in\Bbb N}A$, you can find **this very element** in $\prod_{i\in\Bbb N}A$ and viceversa. So they are more than in bij, they are equal. What's wrong?

Comment: @Manos Let's start from scratch: if $I\sim J$, then $A^I=A^J$, where $A^I$ is the set of functions $f:I\to A$. How so?

Comment: @user26857: Beatiful. Very instructive, thanks.

Comment: @Manos My point is that we *have* to define a ring isomorphism between $R$ and $R\times R$, instead of decreeing they are equal.

Comment: @user26857: I see your point now.