# Alternative examples of free modules without the IBN property

Tags: abstract-algebra, free-modules

I'm trying to search for as many examples of non-IBN free modules as possible. But so far I can only find two examples. One is $End(V)$, where $V$ is a vector space of *countable* dimensions. Another is a similar one, mentioned in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/72723/416552). They both involve an underlying vector space/module of *infinite* dimensions. Are there simpler examples of such modules? Because I can't seem to find any. Is the involvement of *infinite* dimensional objects implicit? Thanks.

Comment: Every (left) Noetherian ring has IBN. So, in a sense, a ring without IBN has to be big.